# If any option from a Group is selected, then all options in other group should get disabled using Bootstrap Multiselect (optgroups)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-multiselect

I am using Bootstrap multiselect (https://davidstutz.github.io/bootstrap-multiselect/)

I have 2 groups inside the dropdown.

Upon selecting any option in top group, all the items in second group should get disabled.

I should be able to select  any of the options from the second group.

My controller to bind the data, the list is grouped by county_category. :

```
public void CHDSList()
    {List<SelectList> CHDSListList = new List<SelectList>();
        ViewData["CHDSList"] = new SelectList((from s in objentity.tbl_CountiesMst.ToList().OrderBy(a => a.County_Code)
                                 select new
                                  {
                                       County_Code = s.County_Code,
                                       County_Name = s.County_Code +" - " + s.County_Name,
                                       County_category = s.County_Category
                                  }), "County_Code", "County_Name", "county_category", 1);


    }
```

In the view, I have this...

```
$('.listbox').multiselect({
        includeSelectAllOption: false,
        buttonWidth: '100%',
        maxHeight: 200,
        enableClickableOptGroups: true   })

@Html.ListBox("ChdListBox", (SelectList)(IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewData["CHDSList"],
         new { @class = "listbox", @style = "text-align:left; multiple=multiple; 
              width:100px;min-width:100%; height:30px; border-color:lightblue" })
```

[multiselect dropdown image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J54VW.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

You can use id property of the optgroup in multiselect to disable the group by using jquery. And dont forget to refresh the multiselect after disabling as shown in the code snippet.
After disabling if you want to select then you must enable it.

Refer this code snippet:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-multiselect/0.9.13/js/bootstrap-multiselect.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-multiselect/0.9.13/css/bootstrap-multiselect.css" type="text/css"/>
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#multiselect').multiselect({
            onChange: function (option, checked, select) {
                var groupId = $(option).closest('optgroup').prop('id')
                if (groupId == "optgroup1") {
                    $('#multiselect optgroup#optgroup2').prop('disabled', true);
                    $('#multiselect').multiselect('refresh');
                }
            }
        })
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>
 <select id="multiselect" multiple="multiple">
        <optgroup label="Group 1" id="optgroup1">
            <option value="1">Option 1</option>
            <option value="2">Option 2</option>
            <option value="3">Option 3</option>
        </optgroup>
        <optgroup label="Group 2" id="optgroup2">
            <option value="4">Option 4</option>
            <option value="5">Option 5</option>
            <option value="6">Option 6</option>
        </optgroup>
    </select>
</body>
</html>
```